# Orçamento em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando criar esse orçamento mas não estou conseguindo! A página esta no CMS joomla e o javascript estou incluído no modulo, então não preciso incluir a biblioteca por que já esta. A ideia é a seguinte: 
 * O cliente digita a quantidade de peças que ele deseja.
 * em seguido escolhe quantas cores essas camisetas terão (cada quanto mais cores fica mais caro)
 * Depois escolhe o tipo de camiseta (aqui não precisa de calculo não)
 * Por fim o ultimo input me traria o calculo
 * O calculo seria assim: Quantidade de cores * 25 / quantidade de peças.

Alguem me ajuda ai please???

```js
<script>
function calcular(){
    var qtde_pecas = parseInt(document.getElementById('qtde_pecas').value, 10);
    var r3 = (document.getElementById('r3').value, 3);
    var r35 = (document.getElementById('r35').value, 3.5);
    var r4 = (document.getElementById('r4').value, 4);
    var r45 = (document.getElementById('r45').value, 4.5);
    var r5 = (document.getElementById('r5').value, 5);
    var r55 = (document.getElementById('r55').value, 5.5);
    var r6 = (document.getElementById('r6').value, 6);
    var r65 = (document.getElementById('r65').value, 6.5);
    document.getElementById('valor_unit1').value =  r3 * 25 / qtde_pecas;
}
 
</script>
```

```html
<form class="orcamento" id="orcamento-pecas">
             <div class="qtde_pecas">
                 <label class="title-pecas">Quantidade de Peças</label><input type="number" id="qtde_pecas" name="qtde-pecas" value="" maxlength="2" size="1" min="1" max="1" onkeyup="calcular();">  
               </div>  
                <div class="qtde_cores">
                 <label class="title-cores">Quantidade de Cores</label>
                    <select id="qtde_cores">
                          <option value="3" id="r3" onkeyup="calcular();">01</option>
                          <option value="3,5" id="r35" onkeyup="calcular();">02</option>
                          <option value="4" id="r4"onkeyup="calcular();" >03</option>
                          <option value="4,5" id="r45"onkeyup="calcular();">04</option>
                          <option value="5" id="r5" onkeyup="calcular();">05</option>
                          <option value="5,5" id="r55" onkeyup="calcular();">06</option>
                          <option value="6" id="r6" onkeyup="calcular();">07</option>
                          <option value="6,5" id="r65" onkeyup="calcular();">08</option>
                   </select>
                  

               </div>  
                <div class="tipo_malha">
                  <label class="title-malha">Tipo de Malha</label>
                <select class="tipo-malha" id="tipo-malha">
                   <option value="">Camiseta PV Branco</option>
                    <option value="">Camiseta PV Colorido</option>
                    <option value="">Camiseta Algodão Branco</option>
                    <option value="">Camiseta Algodão Colorida</option>
                    <option value="">Camiseta Dryfit</option>
                    <option value="">Camiseta Poliamida</option>
                    <option value="">Blusa Moletom Canguru</option>
                    <option value="">Blusa Moletom Ziper</option>
                    <option value="" >Polo Piquet</option>
                    <option value="">Polo PV</option>
                </select>
               </div> 
                
                
               <div class="valor_unit">
              <label class="title-unit">Valor Unitario</label><input type="number" id="valor_unit1" name="valor-unit" value="">    
              </div>  
              
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta pegar o valor do `option` substituir a virgula por ponto para que se possa fazer operação matemática. No select coloque `onchange="calcular();` e retire a função dos options.

```js
function calcular(){
    var qtde_pecas = (document.getElementById('qtde_pecas').value);
    var qtde_cores =(document.getElementById('qtde_cores').value).replace(",", ".");

    document.getElementById('valor_unit1').value =  ((qtde_cores * 25)/qtde_pecas).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form class="orcamento" id="orcamento-pecas">
 <div class="qtde_pecas">
  <label class="title-pecas">Quantidade de Peças</label><input type="number" id="qtde_pecas" name="qtde-pecas" value="" maxlength="2" size="1" min="1" max="1" onkeyup="calcular();">  
 </div>  
 <div class="qtde_cores">
  <label class="title-cores">Quantidade de Cores</label>
  <select id="qtde_cores" onchange="calcular();">
  <option value="3" id="r3">01</option>
  <option value="3,5" id="r35">02</option>
  <option value="4" id="r4">03</option>
  <option value="4,5" id="r45">04</option>
  <option value="5" id="r5">05</option>
  <option value="5,5" id="r55">06</option>
  <option value="6" id="r6">07</option>
  <option value="6,5" id="r65">08</option>
  </select>               
 </div>  
 <div class="tipo_malha">
  <label class="title-malha">Tipo de Malha</label>
  <select class="tipo-malha" id="tipo-malha">
  <option value="">Camiseta PV Branco</option>
  <option value="">Camiseta PV Colorido</option>
  <option value="">Camiseta Algodão Branco</option>
  <option value="">Camiseta Algodão Colorida</option>
  <option value="">Camiseta Dryfit</option>
  <option value="">Camiseta Poliamida</option>
  <option value="">Blusa Moletom Canguru</option>
  <option value="">Blusa Moletom Ziper</option>
  <option value="" >Polo Piquet</option>
  <option value="">Polo PV</option>
  </select>
 </div> 
                
                
 <div class="valor_unit">
  <label class="title-unit">Valor Unitario</label><input type="number" id="valor_unit1" name="valor-unit" value="">    
 </div>  
              
</form>
```

**De acordo com a nova formula matemática dada nos comentários, temos**

```js
function calcular(){
    
    var qtde_pecas = (document.getElementById('qtde_pecas').value);
    if (qtde_pecas<15){
     cincoReais=5;
    }else{
     cincoReais=0;
    }
    
    //if (qtde_pecas!=""){
     var textoOption = document.getElementById('qtde_cores').options[document.getElementById('qtde_cores').selectedIndex].text;
     var qtde_cores =(document.getElementById('qtde_cores').value).replace(",", ".");
     var tipo_malha =(document.getElementById('tipo_malha').value).replace(",", ".");
     document.getElementById('valor_unit1').value =  (((textoOption * 25)/qtde_pecas)+Number(qtde_cores)+Number(tipo_malha)+cincoReais).toFixed(2);
    //}else{
     //alert("digite qtde_pecas");
    //}
}
```

```html
<form class="orcamento" id="orcamento-pecas">
 <div class="qtde_pecas">
  <label class="title-pecas">Quantidade de Peças</label><input type="number" id="qtde_pecas" name="qtde-pecas" value="" maxlength="2" size="1" min="1" max="1" onkeyup="calcular();">  
 </div>  
 <div class="qtde_cores">
  <label class="title-cores">Quantidade de Cores</label>
  <select id="qtde_cores" onchange="calcular();">
  <option value="3" id="r3">01</option>
  <option value="3,5" id="r35">02</option>
  <option value="4" id="r4">03</option>
  <option value="4,5" id="r45">04</option>
  <option value="5" id="r5">05</option>
  <option value="5,5" id="r55">06</option>
  <option value="6" id="r6">07</option>
  <option value="6,5" id="r65">08</option>
  </select>               
 </div>  
 <div class="tipo_malha">
  <label class="title-malha">Tipo de Malha</label>
  <select class="tipo_malha" id="tipo_malha" onchange="calcular();">
  <option value="3,5">Camiseta PV Branco</option>
  <option value="4">Camiseta PV Colorido</option>
  <option value="4,5">Camiseta Algodão Branco</option>
  <option value="5">Camiseta Algodão Colorida</option>
  <option value="6">Camiseta Dryfit</option>
  <option value="7">Camiseta Poliamida</option>
  <option value="8">Blusa Moletom Canguru</option>
  <option value="9">Blusa Moletom Ziper</option>
  <option value="10" >Polo Piquet</option>
  <option value="5">Polo PV</option>
  </select>
 </div> 
                
                
 <div class="valor_unit">
  <label class="title-unit">Valor Unitario</label><input type="number" id="valor_unit1" name="valor-unit" value="">    
 </div>  
              
</form>
```